# Code for workflow rules in Salesforce using console application

Tags: c#, salesforce

Can anyone help me with coding workflow rules in Salesforce? Each workFlow rule consists of:

1. Some criteria that causes the workflow rule to run.
2. Immediate actions that execute when a record matches the criteria.
3. Time-dependent actions that queue when a record matches the criteria, and execute according to time triggers.

Any help regarding this would be appreciable.

Comment: Why is your question in a blockquote? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

For this you don't need coding,  you can simply create workflow **setup > Build > Create > Workflow Rules** then check for the formula field value in the workflow condition and make the work flow to fire based on the value.

Comment: Hi, I wanted to Implement Work Flow Activites in Slaesforce using C# language. Any References regarding this would be appreciable.